# Sum of one field minus sum of another SSRS Expression

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, sum, calculated-columns

I have a SSRS report I'm working on. What I would like to do is get the value of one field from its own dataset and subtract the value of another field from a different dataset. I can do this; however, the values are grouped so rather than giving me an individual value it gives me: (sum of **all** completed) - (sum of **all** completed the previous year).
[image]

Here is my expression I am using for the column "Compared to last year"

```
=SUM(Fields!Completed.Value, "MTDSales") - SUM(Fields!Completed.Value, "MTDminus1")
```

`"MTDSales"` and `"MTDMinus1"` are 2 seperate datasets. `MTDSales` Dataset is the current months sales outcomes grouped by company `MTDMinus1` dataset is last years figure for this current month as i am comparing the 2 months separately.

Comment: Any reason you can't get the previous year's data along with the current year's in your query?  Are the names in quotes the names of column groups or the names of two different datasets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to do this in a report where I was pulling current data from one database and older data from a data warehouse and combining. You will need to do a few things:

**1. Establish a match field**

This can be as simple as a single column. If you need to match on multiple fields you will need to add a calculated field to each dataset that you can match on. Assuming you need to match on company and financial year and each dataset returns one year of data, this might look something like `match_id` (assuming numeric values - otherwise you might need to use | or something as a separator):

```
`="A" & Fields!fin_year.Value & "B" & Fields!cust_id.Value`
```

**2. Retrieve the data to the source field.**

In your tablix add a column as you have to hold the looked up value:

```
=Lookup(Fields!matchId.Value, Fields!matchId.Value, Fields!Completed.Value, "MTDminus1")
```

**3. Use the data**

Now you can aggregate the data or do whatever further calculations you wish as if the field was part of your original dataset.

Comment: Hi SMM I dont see why i would need to do all that just to get the result of 1 column  - another Grouped on Company, Surely there is an  expression that can be written that contains the "group by" function as both datset have company in it.You are able to group by a parameter so why not a field "=Fields(Parameters!GroupBy.Value).Value"

Comment: How will you correlate to get the correct company sum on each row? I'm not sure that SSRS has a function that will do this in one step. This worked for me :-) It shouldn't be all that much work to implement it.

Comment: I see what you mean, how will it know how to distinguish What company the value is for. I will try and follow your steps Thanks